# Xcode 8: app submission validation error with pkg or mpkg for an iOS app archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode8

Had just done an Xcode 7.3.1 built iOS app update to the App Store a few weeks ago with no problems.   Now that a new Xcode is out I always do a TestFlight rebuild of the same update to make sure no regressions were introduced by Apple.

Ran into an error today I've never seen and cannot find any info on with Xcode 8.   The error is at the very end - on validating the archive prior to submission.   Happens both when manually validating the app, or attempting to upload the app to Apple.   Screenshot attached below.

Same project still builds/archives/validates fine using Xcode 7.3.1.

Anyone hit this Xcode 8 problem know what causes it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found someone posted a similar question to mine with this same problem and it was answered there.  I have up voted that answer as it works and am cross-linking it here for others [Must use MinimumOSVersion in info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715647/cant-upload-ipa-from-xcode-8-the-info-plist-indicates-a-ios-app-but-submitt)

Best action though is to delete this from the info.plist, this should not be added manually for an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

- run Product->Clean and try again
- try to upload it with the Application Loader (Xcode->Open Developer Tools). This often gives you a more detailed error description.

Comment: No change on clean.   Same error.   I do not usually use App loader, installed it and it did not report any errors.  I'll see if TestFlight accepts the ipa it uploaded.

Comment: I can report this is a valid work around until Apple identifies the problem with Xcode validation i have reported here.  I was able to submit using this App loader separately and the app was accepted for the public app store.

Comment: After upgrading to Sierra, this problem now also happens with Application Loader 3.6