# Can't Upload .ipa from Xcode 8, "The info.plist indicates a iOS app, but submitting a pkg or mpkg."

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10, xcode8, ipa

I am trying to submit my app. It is written in swift 3 and has an iOS 10 deployment target. So, I need to use Xcode 8. When I create an archive everything goes fine. I have even looked into the .ipa and everything seems fine.

But, every time I get this error: 
**The info.plist indicates a iOS app, but submitting a pkg or mpkg.**

No idea what's going on. I'm not using any frameworks. No cocoapods. Very simple app.

Edit: Still no information on this. I have made a support request with Apple so we will see if that provides any new info. I can't be the only person experiencing this bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:** See Peter's answer. According to him, the `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key ("Minimum system version") is obsolete and should be removed. If that works for you, upvote his answer instead as that would be a better solution than this if it works.

---

**Original Answer:**

I was encountering this issue when updating a very old app. I was able to fix it  by changing my Info.plist.

I had to change the `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key ("Minimum system version") to `MinimumOSVersion` ("MinimumOSVersion").

**Before**

[image: Before]

**After**

[image]

Comment: That's it! How did you figure that one out?

Comment: @JoelKlabo I had one app that worked and one app that didn't. This was the only difference that I found between each app's Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. It would be so easy for Apple to improve their error codes, I'm always searching Stack Overflow for people experiencing the same cryptic messages that I get...

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode 8.3, you should delete the `Minimum system version` (`LSMinimumSystemVersion`) entry from your info.plist. You do not need to rename it. If your app is that old, you may find other superfluous or conflicting keys as well. Another common one is the main nib file key, which conflicts with a main storyboard key.

Comment: this worked, thanks.  any other keys that are obsolete?

Comment: I haven't been upgrading old apps lately, so I'm not sure. I seem to recall there were others.

Comment: I don't see any docs saying that these keys are obsolete. Could you please point out at them?

Comment: More recent docs now say that key is for macOS and it is simply not listed for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Answer (score -1):

even if you never imported any frameworks, something might be produced automatically.

So please make sure your project has never any frameworks in it.
If you are not sure, when you export your archive file to .ipa, Xcode will code sign your bundle.

In that list, if you see any framework besides your main app bundle, it occurs.

So let me know the status of your project in the aspect I mentioned above.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

fix!
i had the same problem and i fix it.
you can export your app (no click on "upload to app store" but "export" in the archive menu) and then use "application loader" to send your app

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I tried that and I got the same error in Application Loader too.